# Flash: is there any good reason for doing everything manually?

Tags: flash

I received a Flash job to do the other day and none of it was done programatically. All transitions, rollovers, etc., were done with the built-in button states, layers, and all that stuff that I hardly ever work with except through code (since you can do it all by programming custom MCs). All the tweens actually seem to have been done by hand (right clicking “make tween” or whatever). Most problematically, a menu that was six items high was actually made by doing 6 layers in several places, so changing it involved going to all those places and changing.

I do not need help with the app as it required simple mods (all work ×20, basically). However, my question is this: is it possible that the developer used some tool to actually make all those menus and so forth? Or did he really make them pixel by pixel instead of doing them programatically (write once, reuse forever)?

The way he/she did it seems foolish to me, but I’m asking here to make sure that I’m not the one missing the boat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author may have been a designer ... easier to read documentation on Flash vs learning to program ... some times brute force for some people is easier then a little time spent to get something reusable and customizable ...

Comment: thanks. that was my thought as well, but I'm just wondering if there is any other way that this result could have been achieved.

Answer (score 2):

you are not missing the boat : )

Flash is a great tool, but it inherits the quirks of its long history. It was primarily a design tool in the begining, the code aspect took off later. And to this day flash is both  a coding platform and a designer tool. This can be a good / creative thing but it can also lead to very messy projects being built.

Comment: Thanks David. If nobody comes in mentioning some tool that I don't know about, you'll get best answer :)

True that about Flash and its history. But without its history, it would be like Silverlight: too young to rock and roll. On a tangent here: why does Microsoft, of all companies, not know how long it takes to build a good platform?

Comment: Microsoft knows this. Tha goal of Silverlight is not to convert the Flash community into dotnetters. It is to enable the dotnetters to build RIA:s. It's the same tactics as when they constructed WebForms to mimic Windows Forms so that the existing developers could start building web apps. We now know that this tactic was a huge success.